# The images in my Tabs is stretch and it does not look good.How can i "unstretch" it?

Tags: android, image, tabs

Thanks in advance.Here is some code and image.

Here is the Image.
http://s904.photobucket.com/user/fookywooky/media/sof_zpsb7c18f62.png.html

This is my code in the Main Activity (onCreate)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hostTab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    hostTab.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());

    //setting tabs(images)
    mIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_tab);
    //hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150,50));

    mIntent = new Intent(this, ContactUsActivity.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("contactUs").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contact_us_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contact_us_tab);

    mIntent = new Intent(this, TravelDetailsActivity.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("travelDetails").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.travel_details_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.travel_details_tab);

    mIntent = new Intent(this, PortGuide.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("portGuide").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.port_guide_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.port_guide_tab);

    mIntent = new Intent(this, MoreMenu.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("more").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.more_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.more_tab);

}
```

This is the home_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/home_blue">
</item>
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/home_gray">
</item>
```

And this is the xml for the main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="bottom">
        </TabWidget>

     </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Please help.Thanks in advaance

Comment: Attach screenshots about how "stretched" images is looking and how you want it to look like..

Comment: Sorry. i forgot to put the image link and thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="bottom">
        </TabWidget>

     </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Try using of images directly to your id tab widget , it 'll work

Edited:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But can you tell me how can I do that?I'm new to android programming.:(

Comment: As Vipul Purohit said , add screenshots then its easy to say how to .

Comment: @abdroidNoob try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not.:(

Comment: First of all, i would like to thank you for the time you are giving me. But it looks the same.:(

Comment: try using below in your home_tab.xml
android:dither="true"
android:shape="rectangle"

Comment: Unfortunately, the image was not displayed when I added the 2 attributes in <item>. Argh!!!It's bumming me out. My head is hurting  right now.:(

Comment: give me some solutions.:(

Comment: just say wat are all activities you going to do in your projects . i 'll workpout on tat nd say.

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying sir. :(

Comment: i asked about your ful project structure , wat are things are there like tat. And one thing i'm also a learner but not begineer tat it so just call be my name . okay ah ? :)

Comment: oh ok sir.But i think i can do it myself.It is a matter of making images for medium,low etc for the drawables.:) thanks for the help.

Comment: Tats fine ,  okay madam  carry on   :)